# TypeScript: Use of extend + Generic leads to Error in this example

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In the following minimal example I get the typescript error: `TS2339: Property 'creationDate' does not exist on type 'B[keyof B]`. I hope you can help me to find a way to express this usecase in a better way, so that this error doesn't happen.

```js
interface Entry<V> {
    value: V;
    creationDate: string
}

type Book = PaperBook | AudioBook;

interface PaperBook {
    title: Entry<string>;
    numPages: Entry<number>;
}

interface AudioBook {
    title: Entry<string>;
    duration: Entry<number>;
}

function getCreationDate<B extends Book>(book: B, key: keyof B) {
    return book[key].creationDate; // <- Error happens here
}
```

See this [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKLigTwDwDUB8yA3gLABQylyAbnADYCuEAXMrgNzlXIJQRxhgAexAARAS2QBnMFFABzcgF9y5MJgAOKAEJChAa2QBeZAAU4WqLoPIAPsgCCDACbDr%20zmXKhIsRCnNLd2IuKkEwOkl0WRwZORB5fE9uEAYAW3N5CClWaKxsVLSAI2gk5VUyH2h4JEcXNz1DUgow4AiojFjZBTKWymcGKAFhEFzOgvSSqF6VLzIYBhAEQRFkLLAAYT5hkXFIbG1kCAAPSBBnKWR3fAAKIsbWbQAaZH0ITFY3zCEYK4BKEJ9ZB8MCDEDIe4GADaXwAugA6Xj8FZiCTsZAAegxyGwAFo0FAoEIoMgABYWLQgS6k6AQZRAA)

In `getCreationDate()` I am trying to access `book[key].creationDate` which gives an error. It looks like I need to somehow tell typescript that no matter what key we use to access my `book` object, I promise you will always find an `Entry` object there.

Maybe the problem lies in `<B extends Book>`? What i actually would want to express here is something like:

"`B` is either `PaperBook` or `AudioBook`" or "`B` is one of the types that underly the union type `Book`"

Hope this makes sense and you have a solution for me, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`extends` means that `B` could include additional properties which have any value, not necessarily an `Entry`.  One way to fix this is to require that all values on `B` are an `Entry` like so:

```
function getCreationDate<B extends Book & Record<string, Entry<any>>>(book: B, key: keyof B) {
    return book[key].creationDate;
}
```

`B` `extends` the `Record`, so we don't actually widen the key type.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/Nd3r0w)

Normally I would say that you don't want a generic at all here and that you should just require `book` to be a `Book`, but with different keys on the two branches of the union that is difficult.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful. One question: If we write `<B extends Book & Record<string, Entry<any>>>` this means that B extends the interesection between Book and the Record type, right? Why does this mean that B can't include additional properties? (as you wrote in the beginning: extending means having all that properties plus potentially more)

Comment: `B` *can* have additional properties, but those properties must have a value of type `Entry<any>` due to the constraint of the `Record<string, Entry<any>>` type.

Answer (score 0):

It is not safe because `B extends Book` can have other keys. Consider the following (following the definitions in the original post):

```js
const naughtyBook = {
    title: { value: "title", creationDate: "today" },
    numPages: { value: 200, creationDate: "yesterday" },
    badValue: "Not an entry",
}

getCreationDate(naughtyBook, "badValue");
```

This will clearly fail.

Comment: `keyof Book` only includes `"title"` as this is the only key which on on both branches of the `Book` union type.

Comment: @LindaPaiste thanks, you're right. It does work but for the wrong reason. I'll edit my answer to remove that part.